# Autosend email on submit feedback form using html and Javascript

Tags: jquery, html, sendmail, html-email, feedback

I have created one html form with following fields:

- Name (Text Box)
- Email (Text Box)
- Comments (Text area)

and a Submit button to submit the form.

I want to receive an email once the user submits the form successfully. How do I do this?

(Sorry for my poor English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending an email can only be done with server-side technology, it can't be achieved with html/javascript
Please write down what server technology are you using and I'll update the answer

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this automatically by HTML or javascript (unless you don't mind prompting the user to send the email via a `mailto:` link).

You'd need to do with with some server side programming, such as PHP, or .NET. Most, if not all, server side programming languages have their own mail libraries.